# How to use method within if in Prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

This is my code:

```
if(substr( _PS_VERSION_, 0, 3 ) === "1.7"){
    use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Payment\PaymentOption;
}
```

This code does not work.

it only works if I remove if statement. like this:

```
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Payment\PaymentOption;
```

How can I use with using if?

Comment: What works when and why? Explain what the problem is

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: @Andreas I edited my question.

Comment: @GhostCat I edited my question

Comment: "does not work" is not a working problem description. Error message, does the wrong thing,... How exactly does it not work? Again: please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (version_compare(_PS_VERSION_, '1.7.0.0', '>=')) {
    use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Payment\PaymentOption;
}
```